# Systemd write to file after killing service

Tags: python, systemd, systemctl

I have my Python script, which is started via systemd .service file (mine is called skriptaRFM.service). In my Python script I write some values in files and when I kill service I want to write in those files some lines. I read on forums about Kill functions in service files but I don't know which one is the right one for me. I have except function in my script but it won't execute it if I stop service.

Can anyone tell me what can I do? Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you manually killing a process? And is it necessary to write those things only when kill is triggered or anytime before also?

Comment: I already found a solution for my problem